# notifyItemInserted() is having same effect on list as notifyDataSetChanged() when I only want last item in list updated

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The problem that I am having is that when a user adds a comment the entire list refreshes because I have `notifyDataSetChanged();` set on the `CommentAdapter`. Everything jumps, and refreshes and I want it to be smoother, so I decided to use `notifyItemInserted();` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged();`, but it isn't doing anything different.

`notifyItemInserted();` should only update the last item or the newest item added to the list, so why is everything being refreshed/updated...?

Can someone tell me how to fix this? Only want last item added to list to be "added"/"updated"/whatever, not the entire list because if many people start commenting everything is always reloading...

In my `readComments();` what I have now is `mCommentAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mCommentList.size() - 1);`, and what I had before was `mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`, but they are having the same effect. How can I fix this?

**CommentsActivity**

```
public class CommentsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CommentAdapter mCommentAdapter;
    private List<Comment> mCommentList;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    EditText mAddComment;
    ImageView mImageProfile;
    TextView mPost;

    String mPostId;
    String mPublisherId;
    String mNotificationId;

    FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comments);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mCommentList = new ArrayList<>();
        mCommentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(this, mCommentList, mPostId);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mCommentAdapter);

        mAddComment = findViewById(R.id.add_comment);
        mImageProfile = findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        mPost = findViewById(R.id.post_comment);

        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        mPost.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (mAddComment.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(CommentsActivity.this, "Can't send empty comments", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                addCommentNotification(mPublisherId, mPostId);
            }
        });

        getImage();
        readComments();
    }

    private void getImage() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if (user != null)
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageurl()).into(mImageProfile);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void readComments() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments").child(mPostId);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mCommentList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Comment comment = snapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
                    mCommentList.add(comment);
                }

                mCommentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(CommentsActivity.this, mCommentList, mPostId);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mCommentAdapter);
                mCommentAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mCommentList.size() - 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you know that `notifyItemInserted()` is refreshing the whole list, if you are adding one comment `notifyItemInserted()` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` will have the same effect but the former is much more efficient

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan the problem is that when I am in my CommentsActivity and I scroll down, or even if I don't, if someone adds a new comments when I am going through the list of comments EVERYTHING REFRESHES and it shoots my to the top of the list... Also, the username and profile picture are in the activity near the comments and they "refresh" everytime a comment is added. Know some way to fix this?

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan actually what I did was remove the ValueEventListeners and replaced them with SingleEventListeners and that is okay, but when someone or when I add a comment it doesn't show up until I leave the activity and come back... I want the comment to appear right away, as soon as you hit send without having to exit the activity and come back, but also without "refreshing" all the other 100 comments that a post could have.

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan are not in one document...? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: 1) singleValueEventListener will trigger only once, and when you leave the activity it is destroyed, so when you go back the whole data will be read again

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan exactly... It is okay because at least when another user is looking through the comments and for example I or someone else adds a comment it doesn't refresh straight away and shoot you to the top of the comments list, but I was wondering, I mean there has to be a way for the comment to be inserted without it disrupting the other users by refreshing the whole list. I thought that I could achieve this with notifyItemInserted();...

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan I guess bottom line is, Can I insert a comment without it refreshing the whole list? I like the way ListenerForSingleValueEvent works, but when I post a comment it doesn't show up until I refresh the page...

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan Can we chat? Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214458/discussion-between-jmb-and-abhinav-chauhan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you should be using a `ChildEventListener`:

Your `readComments()` must be like this:

```
private void readComments() {

//your reference
DatabaseReference ref =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Comments").child(mPostId);


//the child listener

ChildEventListener listener = new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

// A new comment has been added
Comment comment = dataSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class);
mCommentList.add(comment);

//Notify adapter
mCommentAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mCommentList.size() - 1);
}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {


}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
};

//attach the listener
ref.addChildEventListener(listener);


}
```

Comment: Hey, what's up buddy! Thank you so much works perfectly when I have to insert a comment. What about if I want to remove a comment, same thing but in the onChildRemoved? I tried to do that, but what happens is when I delete a comment I get another line right below the original comment with that same exact comment... How can I delete the comment if I need to?

Comment: Try update, the callback `onChildRemoved` will trigger when you delete an item from the database.

Comment: Okay, so now when I delete the comment what happens is the list rearranges itself and the first comment in the list goes to the bottom instead of it just deleting the comment... Maybe it's the notifyItemRangeChanged or something?

Comment: It only is actually removed if I exit the activity and then re-enter, but I want it to be removed right away... What do you think?

Comment: Okay look I suggest you ask a new question, about removing. To avoid extended comments and to stay in the scope of the original question. When you ask a new question use the new code that you used.

Comment: Bro, but you basically already answered it, just something is making the list rearrange itself instead of actually deleting the comment... You want me to ask another question?

Comment: I will remove the update and yes as it doesn't relate to your original question, you have to ask a new question (add more details on how you are removing the items).

Comment: Okay I will, please have a look at it though

Comment: Don't worry alot of people will see your question, but you have to be clear on what you did so you get a useful answer, if I see your question I will help don't worry :)

Comment: You're right man! Thanks! I posted I really hope you see it :)

Comment: @JMB i think a `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` is the solution to all of your UI updating problems

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan Hey buddy, I solved the problem you were helping me with the other day. The above solution worked quite nicely!